# there is this problem in my next-oauthcongiguration it give me this error

Tags: next.js, oauth, verification

Error 403: access_denied
Request details: o2v=2 service=lso response_type=code theme=glif redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google state=hWbXzL-pgbtkFjd_S1mLTl9cV7M-XDj2pTQLI6DUxco code_challenge_method=S256 flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow client_id=1008844154176-1k4g5qrt8mtp6pv6cb73mmf0ofbbhsm8.apps.googleusercontent.com code_challenge=mC0s5CdluZcIKCNekWRu3d62xnaOVv7dgDlbP2Zbsiw access_type=online scope=openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/useri

give me the solution